# Difficulty identifying outgoing and incoming calls (when app is open or closed)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When there are outgoing and incoming calls, toast should appear on the screen but it does not appear. Is the code incorrect?
Manifast premissions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```

Manifast (receiver):

```
 <receiver android:name=".model.CallReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

MainActivity

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, READ_PHONE_STATE)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this, new String[]{READ_PHONE_STATE} , 369);
        }
```

class:

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context , Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getStringExtra( TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE )==TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK){
            showToastMsg(context,"phone call is Started...");
        }else { if (intent.getStringExtra( TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE )==TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE){
            showToastMsg(context,"phone call is Ended...");
        }else { if (intent.getStringExtra( TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE )==TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING){
            showToastMsg(context,"Incoming Call...");
        }
        }
        }
    }

    private void showToastMsg(Context c,String msg) {
        Toast.makeText( c, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the service to handle incoming or outgoing calls when the app is closed.
Manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".services.CallRecevier">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
    <service
            android:name=".services.CallService"
            android:exported="false" />
```

CallReceiver

```
    public class CallRecevier extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            Intent svc = new Intent(context, CallService.class);
            TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String phoneNumber) {
                    super.onCallStateChanged(state, phoneNumber);
                    if (state == 1 || state == 2) {
                        if (phoneNumber != null && !phoneNumber.equals("")) {
                            svc.putExtra("num", phoneNumber);
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                                context.startForegroundService(svc);
                            } else {
                                context.startService(svc);
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (state == 0) {

                        context.stopService(svc);
                    }
                }
            }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Timber.e("Error: %s", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

CallService

```
public class CallService extends Service {
     
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();

     
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ComponentName startForegroundService(Intent service) {
        if (service.getStringExtra("num") != null) {
            String number = service.getStringExtra("num");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),number,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return super.startForegroundService(service);
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) { 
    if (intent != null && intent.getStringExtra("num") != null) {
        String number = intent.getStringExtra("num");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),number,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }   
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer but it does not work. Do I need to change the MainActivity code further?
Plus I want toast messages to appear when there are incoming and outgoing calls and I did not understand where to put them in your code.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to add anything extra.I edited the answer for you. I hope it works fine if you have the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it is working on android 11 and 9

in manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".Receivers.CallReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Call Receiver

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    private static boolean ring = false, callReceived = false, isIncoming = false;
    private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
    String phoneNumber, extraState;
    int currentState = 0;
    MediaRecorder recorder;
    SharedPref sh;
    CallLogs callLogs;
    String phNumber, dir;

    @SuppressLint("UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver")
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        sh = new SharedPref(context);
        audioFileRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Audio Files");

        phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        extraState = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        startCallService(context, intent);


    }

    private void startCallService(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (extraState != null) {

            if (extraState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {

                currentState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;


                phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

                if (phoneNumber != null) {

                    Toast.makeText(context, "Off hock" + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (ring) {

                        callReceived = true;

                    }

                    if (lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                        isIncoming = false;

                        Toast.makeText(context, "onOutgoingCallStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {

                        isIncoming = true;
                        Toast.makeText(context, "onIncomingCallAnswered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    startRecording(context);


                }


            } else if (extraState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {

                phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);


                if (phoneNumber != null) {

//                    Toast.makeText(context, "Idle" + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (ring && !callReceived) {

                        ring = false;

                    }
                    callReceived = false;

                    if (lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                        //Ring but no pickup-  a miss

                        uploadCallLog(context);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "onMissedCall", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    } else if (isIncoming) {

                        Toast.makeText(context, "onIncomingCallEnded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        uploadCallLog(context);

                        if (recorder != null) {
                            recorder.stop();
                        }

                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(context, "onOutgoingCallEnded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        uploadCallLog(context);


                        if (recorder != null) {
                            recorder.stop();
                        }

                    }


                }

                currentState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;


            } else if (extraState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

                currentState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;


                if (phoneNumber == null)
                    phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

                if (phoneNumber != null) {

                    ring = true;
                    isIncoming = true;
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Ring" + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    context.startService(new Intent(context, UploadNewCallLog.class));
                }


            }

            lastState = currentState;


        } else if (phoneNumber != null) {
            //setIntent(context, Constants.TYPE_CALL_OUTGOING);

            Toast.makeText(context, "Outgoing" + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }

   }
```